# Need help in writing in Case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need help in writing the a case statement which will allow me to put the data in two different scenarios.

I have a data of about 10 million rows and need to filter the data based on time.

If the data is something like this:

There is a column called `CALL`. It consists of time of call(means what time the call came).

Now the scenario is if the call came in between 8 am- 12pm(noon) it should come under one category and if the call comes under after 12pm-4pm it should comes under another category.

So it should be something like this:

```
case 
 when 
      call between (8am-12pm) then 'abc' 
 when
      call between (12pm- 4pm) then 'def'
 when 
      call after 4pm then it should comes under next day means next day morning 'abc'
```

I know may be it is simple but I am not able to figure it out.

How can this be done?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2008?

Comment: yes I am using sql server 2008 only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
case
    when datepart(hour,[call]) < 8 then 'abc'
    when datepart(hour,[call]) between 8 and 11 then 'abc'
    when datepart(hour,[call]) between 12 and 15 then 'def'
    when datepart(hour,[call]) >= 16 then 'abc'
end
```

Obviously the first two clauses could be combined, but I wasn't sure what you wanted to do with calls between midnight and 8am.

**Edit**
You didn't specify what happens between 4pm and 8pm but you should be able to figure it out!

**Edit** Corrected `between` clauses (thanks @Andriy).  @Shahsra - that now means that a `call` value of exactly midday will go to 'def' but 11:59 will go to 'abc'. Of course you can easily tweak it if that isn't quite what you wanted.  The key thing is that `datepart(hour,[call])` is what you need to base your clauses on.

Comment: The second condition should be `between 8 and 11`, the third `between 12 and 15`, and the last one `>= 16`.

Comment: so in the first when condition and the last when condition for <8 and >16 goes to next day 8-12 'abc' data...but as I checked this query its showing me that those calls between 8-16 residing in the same day data 'abc' not in the next day data....

Comment: I've tried the query with an arbitrary datetime column in one of my big tables and it appears to work.  Can you give the exact query you've tried and the results you're getting?

Comment: Hi Sir Crispalot, it seems to be working...Thanks a lot Crispalot.